# Can't make jQuery display correctly valid class upon success

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm having some trouble validating a form:

- When the validation returns **error**, it displays a span element
  containing a cross image and a message, which is as expected.
- **However**, when the validation is **successful**, it **displays multiple span elements**, **one next to the other**, containing a checkmark image (sorry, can't upload an image 'cause I'm a newbie here).

#### Code:

**jQuery Validation:**

```
$("#signupform").validate({...
    errorClass: "error",
    validClass: "valid",
    errorElement: "span",

    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },

    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    },

    success: function(label) {
        label.addClass('valid').removeClass('error');
    }
});​
```

**HTML Form:**

```
                   ...          
<div class="field">
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />                    
   <span id="email_status"></span>  
</div>
<div class="field">
   <label for="username">Username:</label>
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />  
   <span id="username_status"></span>   
</div>
<div class="field">
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />                      
</div>
<div class="field">
   <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm password:</label>
   <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" />                    
</div>
...
```

**Note:** "email_status" and "username_status" are specific for ajax availability validation.

CSS:

```
#signupform span{  
    width:auto;
    height:16px;
    padding-left:30px;  
    margin-left:10px; 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    font-family: Avant Garde, Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}


#signupform span.valid  {
  background:url("../images/tick.png") left center no-repeat;
}

#signupform  span.error{
  background:url("../images/error.png") left center no-repeat;
  color:#B94A48; 
}
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an check condition in the success function..

```
success: function(label) {
    if(!label.hasClass('valid')){
        label.addClass('valid')
    }
    label.removeClass('error');
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$("#signupform").validate({
    rules: {
        password: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        password: {
            required: "Este campo es requerido."
        }
    },
    errorClass: "error",
    validClass: "valid",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $('.field span').remove();
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    success: function(label) {
        $('.field span:gt(0)').remove();
        var $label = $(label);
        if (!$label.hasClass('valid')) {
            $label.addClass('valid');
        }
        $label.removeClass('error');
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/DwbcT/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Sushanth. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. The html generated is : `code` <span for="password" generated="true" class="valid" style=""></span> <span for="password" generated="true" class="valid" style=""></span>`code`

Comment: is the label a DOM element or jQuery element .. Is it supposed to be $(label)

Comment: Right. Tried that one but still the same issue. The error class, though, works just fine. It's quite strange.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle

Comment: I've never used a fiddle before but I've just set up something in jdfiddle. It's not working but maybe you can help me a little: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DwbcT/)

Comment: You are using jQuery validate plugin right.. So you need to add the file as a resource to get it work

Comment: Done. Do I have to do anything else? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/coripel/LrJYd/3/)

Comment: Check this .. I have updated it .. http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/DwbcT/2/  .. You have added jQuery to it.. You need to add jQuery validate.js file

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks! The issue now reproduces exactly.

Comment: Check the Updated post .. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for

Comment: It works just fine. Thanks a lot for your help! Do you know why it doesn't work the other way?

Comment: @coripel .. I have not worked much with the validate plugin .. So I am not exactly sure.. :)

Comment: Ha, ha. No prob! You've been much helpful already. Thanks again.

Comment: @coripel .. Glad to have helped ..:)